# How to export table data into PDF and print functionality in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to export my dynamic table data into Excel, PDF and print. But not able to understand which angular material use and npm plugins to export table data as PDF and with option Print. Would you please give suggestions and help to complete this issue?

I am able to export the data as Excel, but not able to export as PDF and still looking for Print functionality.

Answer (score 1):

thank you and I am able to print the data from HTML table. Use the below code in your .ts file by passing id as I passed.

```
print(): void {
    let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=auto,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Print tab</title>
      <style>
      //........Customized style.......
      </style>
    </head>
<body onload="window.print();window.close()">${printContents}</body>
  </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for exporting table to Excel you can refer to [this](https://medium.com/@madhavmahesh/exporting-an-excel-file-in-angular-927756ac9857)

and for Print, you can use javascript code in ts:
this works for reactive form "this.formName.getValue()"
but if you are using the traditional way
you just need to pass formvalue to variable "a"
rest you can get value in `document.write(${a.name})`

```
print(formValue){
        let popupWin;
        let a: type = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(formValue));
        popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 
         'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto,toolbar=no,titlebar=no');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write(`<html> <head>
</head><body onload="window.print();window.close()">
 heya !! ${{ a }}
</body> `)
}
```

you can use typescript code within HTML.

Comment: Hi Ankit, thanks for your reply and I tried with above method. But it is not working for me. Getting a blank page popup by keeping on loading. I need to implement this method in common service and need to call by importing the common service in my component. Then how can we pass form values in that service?

Comment: you are getting blank screen as body tag is empty in function. you need to write something in it. 
<body> </body>.
if you have already created the service. you can put this function in service and take form value as a parameter and replace variable "a" value with it.
rest you can access form value by using "a" variable in body tag. eg: ${{ a.id }}
to get form Value for reactive form use - this.formName.getRawValue()

for normal template form
use - form.value()

Comment: You should pass the id and that id should be same in HTML and your function. Please use the method I kept above and don't forget to pass the ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
public generatePDF()
{
    var data = document.getElementById('contentToConvert');
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
        // Few necessary setting options
        var imgWidth = 208;
        var pageHeight = 295;
        var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
        var heightLeft = imgHeight;

        const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
        let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF
        var position = 0;
        pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
        pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf'); // Generated PDF
    });
}
```

---

By using above function, we can convert the table data into pdf. and pass an id to you table. ....

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mat-Table to store your data, the following will definitely help you: Note: On Button Click downloadPdf() will function.

```
    import 'jspdf-autotable';
    import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
    constructor(){}
    ngOnInit(){}

     documentHeaders = [
    'Work Order #',
    'Product #',
    'Asset',
    'Operator',
    'Task Name',
    'Target Minute',
    'Actual Minute',
    'Productivity %',
    'Status',
    'Start Time',
    'End Time'
     ];
    functionCall(){
    //will return an array with data which is to be displayed}
    downloadPDF() {
    doc.text('Some Text here ', 10, 10);
    const head = [this.documentHeaders];
    let tableArray = new Array();
    let data = this.functionCall('PDF');
    let header: string;
    header = 'Shift Summary ' + formatDate(this.tDate, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en');
    console.log(header);

    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(header, 10, 10);

    ((doc as any).autoTable as AutoTable)({
      head: head,
      body: data,
      theme: 'grid',
      styles: {
        overflow: 'visible',
        cellWidth: 17,
        minCellWidth: 17
        // fillColor: [255, 0, 0]
      },
      headStyles: {
        cellWidth: 17,
        minCellWidth: 17
      },
      didDrawCell: data => {
        console.log(data.column.index);
      }
    });

    doc.save(header + '.pdf');
  }
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with a demo for this?